# Facing issue while uploading image using Graphql and apollo server

Tags: image, graphql, image-uploading, apollo-server

Facing issue with uploading an image using graphql. When I test the following query using postman I get an error (shown below).

Query:

```js
{"query":"mutation($file: Upload) {sendImage(file: $file)
  }","variables":{"file":null}}
```

Error:

> BadRequestError: Invalid JSON in the ‘operations’ multipart field (https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec).

Comment: I am using apollo-server for graphql

Answer (score -1):

By default, the results are sent as `application/json` payload but for file upload, you need to make a multipart request.

you can follow this [link](https://github.com/jaydenseric/graphql-multipart-request-spec) to make multipart request using postman.

[Read more about file upload](https://blog.apollographql.com/file-uploads-with-apollo-server-2-0-5db2f3f60675)

Comment: I did the same change but no improvement

Comment: @vignesh Can you share your multipart request?